# RTP H.264 save and replay

Tags: c++, h.264, rtp

We are interested in saving a H.264 stream and replaying it. Is there any one who experience saving h.264 using winpcap and replaying it. We were able to save H.263 and replay, but same logic does not work for H.264.

We also tried rtpdump tool to save H264 stream, but we were unable to replay it in that format?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An H.264 stream is usually sent as a [Transport Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) (TS). If you want to save it to file then you need to demux it and then mux it to a format suitable for file storage, for example MP4.

You will probably need to disable bframes in your encoder. Saving an RTP H.264 didn't work for me with bframes enabled.

I also advise to use a low keyint value because the dump will only be readable after the first keyframe.

You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to save the incoming stream with this command:

```
vlc -I rc rtp://@:4444 :sout=#std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=output.mp4} :ipv4
```

Replace 4444 with the port number.